# Using a loop to make a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a binary2acii and vise versa `Dictonary` via Python shell. I'm a bit stuck:

1. I make a new `Dictonary`
2. I need to declare, that it goes from 0-127
3. Make a loop to go through all options

I'm new to this.

```
binary2ascii = {}, 
format (127,"08b")   
for i in range(0,127): chr(i)
```

Comment: Where is your actual problem?

Comment: I cant get the loop to print out the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to spend a little more time learning Python essentials.

Anyway, here's a way to make a dictionary that handles both converting a bitstring to a character and vice versa. I just loop over `range(65, 70)` to keep the output small.

```
from pprint import pprint

binary2ascii = {}
for i in range(65, 70):
    bits = format(i, "08b")
    char = chr(i)
    binary2ascii[bits] = char
    binary2ascii[char] = bits

pprint(binary2ascii)
```

**output**

```
{'01000001': 'A',
 '01000010': 'B',
 '01000011': 'C',
 '01000100': 'D',
 '01000101': 'E',
 'A': '01000001',
 'B': '01000010',
 'C': '01000011',
 'D': '01000100',
 'E': '01000101'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can accomplish such 'translation' without the dictionary, like this:

```
def asc2binii(ch):
    return bin(ord(ch))

def bin2ascii(bin_int):
    return chr(int(bin_int, 2))

char_input="a"
binary_repr = asc2binii(char_input)
print(binary_repr)
ch_returned = bin2ascii(binary_repr)
print(ch_returned)
```

will print:

```
0b1100001
a
```

Comment: Fair point. However, the OP doesn't want the leading `0b` on their bitstrings, and a `dict` lookup is _much_ faster than 3 Python function calls.

Comment: Adding formatting will help with `0b`. IMO, if it's intended for a couple of transforms, then it's better to use functions; if it'll be used for many transforms, then, indeed, creating a dictionary will worth it to save on computation. Though if even more performance is needed - may be fall down to C extensions. :)